# Java Image Applet

Tags: applet, java

i am new to java programming. i am trying to create a java applet running in HTML page which will chose any image from your computer by browsing through your directories. So far i was able to display an image in the applet by specifying the path of the image in the code itself. I want to make it dynamic in nature.`

Comment: I actually made something similar many moons ago. You might find the source of that inspirational: http://aasted.org/coppermine/ (source available at the bottom of the page)

Comment: "I want to make it dynamic in nature". - what do you mean?

Comment: *"i am new to java programming."*   It is spelled Java.  Further, put an upper case letter at the start of every sentences to help the reader.  Reading all-lower-case is like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling.  As to the technical question.  Why on earth would I as a potential user, want a trusted applet just to view an image on my own computer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a JFileChooser to your applet and upon selection of a file (image file) create a new BufferedImage to display inside your applet.

Comment: What about signing the applet for allowing access to local files?

Comment: Yes indeed, the jar has to be signed to be able to access the local file system.

Comment: @madth3, if he want to realize it, otherwise he can run from Eclipse without any problems, if just for practice.